# Flutter Aging Person Custom Widget

Tags: android, ios, flutter

So I want to add a bit of spice to my app that I am developing, and had a really good and simple idea for it. There is a age screen page that looks like this right now: (see img below). I want this age screen to have a baby (hear me out) in between the age slider and the continue button. This baby will gradually age as the user moves the slider up and decrease in age as the slider moves down. So when the slider is 10 - it will show a small boy, and when the slider is 90, it will show an elderly man. I want it to be a smooth transition, and it can just be a silhouette (that works the best). What is the best way to do this and if any of you guys can provide a working code snippet I will owe you so much. Thanks! The code is for the screen is located above the image.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:workout_app/Screens/Components/Sign_Up_Screens/screen1.dart';
import 'package:workout_app/Screens/Components/Sign_Up_Screens/screen3.dart';

class screen2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => Main();
}

class Main extends State<screen2> {
  void returnScreen(context) {
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        fullscreenDialog: true,
        builder: (context) => screen1(),
      ),
    );
  }

    
  @override
  void initState() {
    loadData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
  

  @override
  int age = 10;
  bool nextValid = false;

  void toast(String text) {
    final scaffold = ScaffoldMessenger.of(context);
    scaffold.showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .5,
        behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
        content: Text(text),
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
        elevation: 10,
      ),
    );
  }

  void submitData() async {
    if(nextValid == false) {
      toast('Please input your age');
      return;
    }
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setInt('age', age);
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        fullscreenDialog: true,
        builder: (context) => SingleSelectListViewWithLogo(items : ['Tone Up - You want visible muscles with as little mass as possible and a low body fat percentage', 'Bulk Up - You want large, defined muscles, with a low percentage of body fat', 'Get Jacked - You want to lift an insane amount of weight and don\'t care about body fat or muscle definition']),
      ),
    );
  }

  void loadData() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    try {
      int? x = prefs.getInt('age');
      print(x);
      if(x != null) {
        setState(() => {age = x, nextValid = true});
      }
    } catch (Exception){
      //continue;
    }
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Material(
      child: Scaffold(
      body: 
        Container (
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 94, 94, 94)),
          height: size.height,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget> [
              Positioned(
                top: size.height * .06,
                left: size.width * .03,
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    returnScreen(context);
                  },
                  child: Image.asset(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    "assets/images/back2.png",
                    width: size.width * .07,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned (
                top: size.height * .33,
                width: size.width * .9,
                height: size.height * .47,
                left: size.width * .05,
                child: FittedBox(
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                    child: Image.asset(
                      "assets/images/screen2background.png",
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ), 
              Positioned(
                top: size.height * .09,
                left: size.width * .42,
                child: const Text(
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 4, 3, 3)),
                  'Next,'
                )
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: size.height * .15,
                left: size.width * .16,
                child: const Text(
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 42, 42, 42)),
                  'Lets customize your workout!'
                )
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: size.height * .35,
                left: size.width * .15,
                child: const Text(
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0), fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  'What\'s your current age?'
                )
              ),
              Positioned (
                top: size.height * .5,
                left: size.width * .1,
                child: SliderTheme(
                  data: const SliderThemeData(
                    trackHeight: 30,
                    inactiveTrackColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                    activeTrackColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                    thumbColor: Colors.black,
                    disabledActiveTrackColor: Colors.black,
                    disabledInactiveTrackColor: Colors.black12,
                    thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 25.0),
                  ),
                  child: Container (
                    width: size.width * .8,
                    child: Slider(
                      label: "Select Age",
                      value: age.toDouble(),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          age = value.toInt();
                          nextValid = true;
                        });
                      },
                      min: 10,
                      max: 99,
                    )
                  )
                )
              ),
              Positioned (
                top: size.height * .42,
                left: size.width * .28,
                child: Text(
                  age.toString(),
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 40.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned (
                top: size.height * .44,
                left: size.width * .42,
                child: const Text (
                  'years old',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 25.0,
                  ),
                )
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: size.height * .66,
                left: size.width * .1,
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: size.width * .8,
                  height: size.height * .08,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    style: ButtonStyle(                  
                      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(!nextValid ? Color.fromRGBO(69, 75, 85, 1) : Color.fromARGB(255, 23, 100, 22)),
                    ),
                    child: const Text('Continue',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      submitData();
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ]
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Age Screen]

Answer (score 0):

Have a state of the asset location at the beginning of the `State` class:

```
String assetName = 'assets/images/pic.png';
```

Then down below where you load the `Image.asset` use the `assetName` created above to load the image:

```
Center(
  child: AnimatedContainer(
    duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
    curve: Curves.bounceIn,
    height: age * 2.toDouble(),
    child: Image.asset(
      assetName,
    ),
  ),
),
```

Then where you get the updated value of the `Slider` check the value and update the `assetName` accordingly:

```
Slider(
  label: "Select Age",
  value: age.toDouble(),
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
      age = value.toInt();
      nextValid = true;
    });
    if (value > 25) {
      setState(() {
        assetName = 'assets/images/rotated.png';
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        assetName = 'assets/images/pic.png';
      });
    }
  },
  min: 10,
  max: 99,
)
```

[image: Final result]

More info regarding `StatefulWidget` in Flutter: [StatefulWidget class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html)

Comment: Thanks again for this answer! Your answer and Rahul's answer on the other question helped me build the script for the age screen. Thanks!